# ReSharper not running NUnit tests correctly

Tags: c#, nunit, resharper

I'm having some issues with ReSharper and NUnit test running. I have some tests that, for debug purposes, I have changed to *only* contain `Assert.True(true);`. There are multiple Test Fixtures on the class with different parameter values. When I try and run the tests, however, only a few of them run. If I name them all something simple like "A", "B", "C", etc, they all run. I have compiled an album of screenshots on Imgur to document the issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XP8x0.jpg

As you can see on the Warnings page in the last screenshot, it doesn't even pull the full name of the test correctly. They get chopped off at various lengths. I can't  find anything about that error message ("was left pending after its completion") on Google either.

What's going on?

Comment: What version of NUnit and what version of Resharper are you using? NUnit 3 truncates the parameter names when forming the test names because they become too long for some runners. It looks like discovery is returning different test names than running. I am wondering if Resharper is doing the discovery rather than passing it to NUnit.

Comment: We added a fix to not truncate test names by default in NUnit 3.5, that might help. I also found this R# issue, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-452867#u=1452612345361

Comment: That would explain why it worked with simple names...I can try and use a TestFixtureSource instead, or give them a shorter name so R# doesn't get confused

Comment: Is that comment by @Rob Prouse  rather an answer to the question:
"What's going on?"

Comment: Greetings from 2020, we have the same problem except only in one test project out of 8 and the names aren't longer than the others.